# Why is there functional difference between Swipe to pop view controller and poping view controller Programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, backbarbuttonitem

When we Swipe right to Pop view controller/Click Back Button on navigation bar only ViewWillAppear code is called ,but , when we programmatically call [self.navigationcontroller popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; , It behaves differently , first ViewDidLoad is called and then ViewWillAppear is called . How can I achieve behaviour in 1st case using code ?

Comment: ViewDidLoad will *always* be called before ViewWillAppear gets called for the first time.

Comment: @rschmidt my view is already loaded in memory . Stil when I Pop VC view didload gets called again , whereas on view will appear should be called.

Comment: Found the answer ... The view controller was being re instantiated from within the code ! That is why viewdidload was being called. ! Solved the problem .